Clarification on joins
In Oracle I was taught to join as
select * 
from Table_a a, Table_b b, Table_c c
where a.id = b. Id and b.thing = c.thing 

I was using this method, ignoring the training I'd followed to do explicit joins as everyone in my company uses the above approach.
We've moved to SQL server (Azure data studio) and I'm using
select *
from Table_a a 
join Table_b b on a.id = b.id
join Table_c c on b.thing = c.thing

For inner joins I get this.
When I change this to left joins like this
select *
from Table_a a 
left join Table_b b on a.id = b.id
left join Table_c c on b.thing = c.thing

I understand what a left join is, but I'm struggling to understand how the joining works.
Am I telling it - use all records from a, and then return all values from table b with nulls when nothing is found?
The bit I struggle with is the join to c.
Am I using table a as the base so I am looking for all values from a and then anything matching from c as nulls?
What happens if a to b was an inner join and c was then a left join?
Is c left joining to b?
Or left joining to a?
Example:
select *
from Table_a a 
join Table_b b on a.id = b.id
left join Table_c c on b.thing = c.thing

Am I telling it in that scenario that I want the left join to be to b only, so I'm looking for the records only in a, all in b, and matching values with nulls in c?
I get what happens if I use ALL left joins, but if they are mixed and matched I can't get my head around it?

The "Oracle way" was wrong, even on Oracle. Oracle has supported the new way for 25 years now.

Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck. Not a bunch of questions about a bunch of code issues. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"? ) How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? "I understand what a left join is" Clearly, you don't. Why do you write this? (Rhetorical.)

Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

"In Oracle I was taught to join as" I am, once again, confused by Oracle people, do they still think it's the 1980's? We moved on in 1992, and it's 2024 now... Honestly, do these same people ask you to speak Latin, under the belief it's not a dead language?

It's helpful here to remember your formal relational algrebra, where what we think of as a table is one way to express what is formally called a relation.
In this context, the result of joining two relations (A and B) is another relation.

The bit I struggle with is the join to c. Am I using table a as the base so I am looking for all values from a and then anything matching from c as nulls?

No. You can think of it as joining C to result of the A + B join. After all, A  joined to B is just another relation.
In reality, things may not work this way. The database will take shortcuts where it can, in order to improve efficiency and performance. It is even free to re-order your JOINs when actually executing the query, if it thinks the new order is still accurate and will perform better. But semantically, you can think of it as if the join operations work from top down, or left to right, depending on how you format the query.
... oh, and of course also in accordance with how you build parentheses or nesting. If you think A join B on .. left join C on ... is confusing, wait till you see things like A JOIN (B JOIN C ON ...) ON ... (which, btw, you should generally avoid but is perfectly legal and even useful every once in a while).

This has nothing to do with Oracle. The syntax first shown was used in the 1980s and early 1990s. So either you started with Oracle then or you got a bad teacher.
As to left outer joins: Once you outer join a table and then join another table to the outer-joined one, you must outer join it, too.
For instance:
select *
from a 
left join b on b.col_1 = a.col_2
left join c on c.col_3 = b.col_4;

You select an A row. You look for matching B rows. If there is no match, then you get a dummy B row with its col_1 and col_4 set to NULL, just as you decribe. Now you look for matching C rows, but c.col_3 = b.col_4 can never be true, because col_4 is NULL. As we outer join, there is no match, so we get a dummy C row with its columns set to NULL. All fine as desired.
If we had an inner join instead:
select *
from a 
left join b on b.col_1 = a.col_2
inner join c on c.col_3 = b.col_4;

we would outer join B, but as the outer joined dummy row has no match in C, the outer joined row gets dismissed, and you end up with a mere
select *
from a 
inner join b on b.col_1 = a.col_2
inner join c on c.col_3 = b.col_4;

result.
The same thing happens by the way, if you outer join, but then require certain values in the where clause:
select *
from a 
left join b on b.col_1 = a.col_2
where b.col_3 = 123;

renders the outer join a mere inner join, as in an outer-joined row col_3 is null and hence dismissed in the where clause.

Think about joins step by step: after first join you get some intermediate table and then you join 3rd table C on this table

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's probably easiest to just try this all out and see the results:
CREATE TABLE a (id int, col1 varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE b (id int, col1 varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE c (id int, col1 varchar(10));

INSERT INTO a (id, col1) VALUES (1, 'a1'), (2, 'a2'),(3, 'a3');
INSERT INTO b (id, col1) VALUES (1, 'b1'), (2, 'b2'),(4, 'b4');
INSERT INTO c (id, col1) VALUES (1, 'c1'), (3, 'c3'),(4, 'c4');


SELECT *
FROM a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
     ON a.id = b.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN c
     ON b.id = c.id;

+----+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 |  id  | col1 |  id  | col1 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | a1   | 1    | b1   | 1    | c1   |
|  2 | a2   | 2    | b2   | null | null |
|  3 | a3   | null | null | null | null |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+

In this query with all LEFT OUTER JOIN all records from a are selected, and then only the matching records in b and then finally only records from c that match the b records that survived the previous join made it through.

SELECT *
FROM a
  INNER JOIN b 
     ON a.id = b.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN c
     ON b.id = c.id;

+----+------+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | id | col1 |  id  | col1 |
+----+------+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | a1   |  1 | b1   | 1    | c1   |
|  2 | a2   |  2 | b2   | null | null |
+----+------+----+------+------+------+

Switching the first join to an INNER JOIN causes a change in the output. Now records MUST match between a and b to survive the INNER JOIN. Then only the records in c that match between what is left of b will have their values brought through.
You can see this in action here: https://dbfiddle.uk/3pB_Rb_3
